# Turning a development environment into an executable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a virtual environment that has one main `tkinter` script, **16** python file, **5** text files, **3** PNG files and a **subdirectory** where PDFs will be saved. How in the world can I make a `exe` with all these files so that I can move it onto another computer without any of the dependencies or files installed on it?

I have tried `pyinstaller` but I get a `fatal error` when I attempted to run the exe.

How can I create one functional exe? The code is in Python 3.6.

Comment: What error are you getting when running pyinstaller?

Comment: Fatal error could not run script x

Comment: Could you please attach the error log!!!

Comment: It's a GUI so I couldn't get an error log. When I ran the exe from the command line I get `Failed to execute script x`

Comment: probably this question will be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716346/windows-pyinstaller-error-failed-to-execute-script-when-app-clicked