# Failed to execute script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I wrote a simple script in python 3.7 and I coverted it in .exe from cmd with the following line `pyinstaller -w -F -i [myicon.ico] [myscript.py]` . My script works if i launch it from command line (`python myscript.py` ), but it doesn't work when i click on "Myscript.exe" (I have a window with this message :"Failed to execute script Myscript").
I try to create the same script without the icon but result is the same.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Is it the only error? What is your simple script? is pytinstaller installed in the same python? (Just use python -m pyinstaller instead of pyinstaller to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to that post:
[Windows- Pyinstaller Error "failed to execute script " When App Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716346/windows-pyinstaller-error-failed-to-execute-script-when-app-clicked/40720154)

Actually the answer is that python doesn't compile the icon and so you need to manually transfert the icon in the folder containing the .exe.

B