# Windows- Pyinstaller Error “failed to execute script ” When App Clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

I’m New to Python Coding and just finished my first python scripted
I’m trying to publish my programme so that I can install in on another device.

But as soon as I convert it from `.py` to `.exe` with pyinstaller and try to run my programme it gives me the error:

*fatal error: failed to execute scrip*

Code I used in to convert:

```
pyinstaller -w file_name.py
pyinstaller -F file_name.py
pyinstaller -i "c:\\icon_file path" file_name.py
```

am I just missing as step or is there something else I can try to resolve this problem?
I usually code on Visual studio and when I test run everything worked fine.

My `.spec` file:

````
    block_cipher = None


    a = Analysis(['file_name.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\MainUser\\Desktop\\Publishing'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[],
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],                
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher,
                 noarchive=False)
    a.binaries = a.binaries + 
                 [('libsha1.dll','/home/iot/lib/libsha1.dll','BINARY')]
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='file_name',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```
````

Comment: Can you share the code you use please for pyinstaller?

Comment: pyinstaller -w My_File_Name.py ; pyinstaller -F My_File_Name.py ; pyinstaller -i "Path for my Icon_image" My_File_Name.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows- Pyinstaller Error "failed to execute script " When App Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716346/windows-pyinstaller-error-failed-to-execute-script-when-app-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you only have one script, so if you use:

```
Pyinstaller --onefile yourScript.py
```

Replacing `yourScript.py` with the name of your python file in the CMD/Terminal, you shouldn't have any problems.

If you are missing a binary, this should help. For example pyinstaller was missing the currency converter module, so I found and it, got the zip file and then ran this in CMD:

```
Pyinstaller --add-binary "C:\Users\myName\Downloads\eurofxref-hist.zip";currency_converter --onefile myScript.py
```

Where myScript.py is my Python script, and the link is to the folder with the binary zip file.

Comment: Should I run this with a setup.py file?
It only flesh `command prompt ` for 2 sec and the nothing happens.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Create a new folder on your desktop, put your script into it, then open up the CMD in that folder, the paste that code I linked with the script name changed. It should work?

Comment: So my CMD just gave me a new Error. My data is stored in mySql. Error : No module named mysql.connector but it runs fine when I test it in Visual Studio. And i did pip install It before hand

Comment: Oh, I see. Sounds like you do not have the supported binary. You need to find the binary zip file of mysql.connector. I have edited my response to help with the code you need to use when you have it

Comment: Thank Again for all your help. Will keep you updated and let you now if it works.

Comment: I just pip Install MySQL-connector and it run, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is due to a lack of file when packaging.

When you use PyInstaller, you can use it like this:

```sh
python -m PyInstaller .\yourFile.py
```

then, a `yourFile.spec` file is generated under this folder.

you should edit this file, add all project file into `datas`,

```sh
a = Analysis(['yourFile.py'],
         pathex=['D:\\projectPath\\project'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('D:\\projectPath\\project\\*.py', '.'),
                ('D:\\projectPath\\project\\UI\\*.ui', 'UI'),
                ('D:\\projectPath\\project\\other\\*.py', 'other'),
         ],
         ...
    )
```

It's simulated up here, a project that contains the `UI` and `other` folders. It like a tuple, `('full path', 'folder name')`.

If you have *.dll on Windows or *.so on Linux, you must be write into `binaries`:

```sh
a.binaries = a.binaries + [('libsha1.so','/home/iot/lib/libsha1.so','BINARY')]
```

Comment: This Might be a silly question, but the path I should enter ”” 'D:\\projectPath\\project' “”  is it where my file is publish and I made the .exe file or the one where I originally saved it and all the files I used?

Comment: I have added my `.spec` file in my main question

Comment: @TaniaRheeder Maybe I didn't make myself clear, you need run `python -m PyInstaller` twice, The first time we did that I told, The Second you should run `python -m PyInstaller yourFile.spec`.

Comment: @TaniaRheeder ` 'D:\\projectPath\\project'` is your project root path, the *.exe will build in `./dist/startFileName/ *.exe`