# Failed to execute script pygame error dist not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I want to pack my code but I'm getting this error `Failed to execute script` , I'm not sure why, I made sure that I had all my files in the same spot in the dist and checked multiple times if everything was working but for some reason I keep getting the error. I have also repacked my code multiple times and that did not work. `I used pyinstaller`

My code

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption(("Noobs First Game"))
# Start screen
MB = pygame.image.load("Main_bg.png")
MB2 = pygame.image.load("Main_bg2.png")
MB3 = pygame.image.load("Main_bg3.png")
MB4 = pygame.image.load("Main_bg4.png")
# For question's
R = pygame.image.load("Rule.png")
R2 = pygame.image.load("Rule_2.png")
# Sound's and Music
MM = pygame.mixer.music.load("Main_music.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

BG = pygame.image.load("b_g1.png")
# Pause,Mute, and Unmute
M = pygame.image.load("M_1.png")
M2 = pygame.image.load("M_2.png")
P = pygame.image.load("P_1.png")
P2 = pygame.image.load("P_2.png")
UM = pygame.image.load("UM_1.png")
UM2 = pygame.image.load("UM_2.png")
# Game paused
GP = pygame.image.load("GameP1.png")
GP2 = pygame.image.load("GameP2.png")
GP3 = pygame.image.load("GameP3.png")
GP4 = pygame.image.load("GameP4.png")
# When you lose
DD = pygame.image.load("Died1.png")
DD2 = pygame.image.load("Died2.png")
fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white = (255,255,255)

darkred = (200,0,0)

darkgreen = (0,200,0)

green = (0,255,0)

red = (255,0,0)

black = (0,0,0)

blue = (0,0,255)

darkblue = (0,0,200)

# Button class
class button11():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
 
    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
 
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
 
    def isOver(self, pos):
        #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
 
            return False
 
    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                eat.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False
 
white = (250,250,250)
greenbutton5 = button11((0,255,0),175,233,150,55, 'Click Me )')
greenbutton1 = button11((0,255,0),185,320,130,50, 'Click Me )')
greenbutton2 = button11((0,255,0),190,400,120,45, 'Click Me )')
greenbutton6 = button11((0,255,0),10,420,170,60, 'Click Me )')
greenbutton7 = button11((0,255,0),10,420,170,60, 'Click Me )')


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()


def Answers():
    
    an = True

    while an:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((700/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("",10,420,170,60,green,darkgreen,game_intro)
        window.blit(R,(0,0))
        
        if greenbutton6.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(R2,(0,0))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)





    

#######
# Start Screen 
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",40)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()

    
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',75)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("",175,233,150,55,green,darkgreen,main_loop)
        button("",185,320,130,50,red,darkred,quitgame)
        button("",190,400,120,45,blue,darkblue,Answers)
        window.blit(MB,(0,0))

        if greenbutton5.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(MB2,(0,0))
        if greenbutton1.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(MB3,(0,0))
        if greenbutton2.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(MB4,(0,0))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)



def main_loop():
    global pause
    global lose


    # Player class
    class Player:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.speed = 6
            self.fall = 0
            self.idle = [pygame.image.load("Player_idle1.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle2.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle3.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle4.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle5.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle6.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle7.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle8.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle9.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idle10.png")]
            
            self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_lidle1.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle2.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle3.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle4.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle5.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle6.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle7.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle8.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle9.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_lidle10.png")]

            self.run = [pygame.image.load("Player_run1.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run2.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run3.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run4.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run5.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run6.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run7.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_run8.png")]
            
            self.jump = [pygame.image.load("Player_Jump.png")]

            self.lrun = [pygame.image.load("Player_lrun1.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun2.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun3.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun4.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun5.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun6.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun7.png"),
                        pygame.image.load("Player_lrun8.png")]

            self.ljump = [pygame.image.load("Player_lJump.png")]

            self.direction = "run"
            self.direction = "jump"
            self.direction = "lrun"
            self.direction = "ljump"
            self.direction = "idle"
            self.direction = "idlel"
            self.run = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.run]
            self.jump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.jump]
            self.lrun = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.lrun]
            self.ljump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.ljump]
            self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.idle]
            self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.idlel]

            self.isJump = False
            self.JumpCount = 10
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.next_frame_time = 0
            self.fps = 10
            self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            self.anim_index = 0
            self.jump_height = 2
        def get_rect(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            return self.rect
        def draw(self):
            if self.direction == "run":
                image_list = self.run
            if self.direction == "jump":
                image_list = self.jump
            if self.direction == "lrun":
                image_list = self.lrun
            if self.direction == "ljump":
                image_list = self.ljump
            if self.direction == "idle":
                image_list = self.idle
            if self.direction == "idlel":
                image_list = self.idlel
                

            # Is it time to show next frame?
            time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
                # seconds till next frame
                inter_time_delay = 1000 // self.fps
                self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
                # switch to next frame
                self.anim_index += 1
                if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                    self.anim_index = 0

            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0
            player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

            pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect(), 2 )
            player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

            player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
            player_rect.centerx += 3
            player_rect.centery -= 17
            window.blit(player_image, player_rect)

    # Platform class
    class Platform:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.log = pygame.image.load("log.png")
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.log = pygame.transform.scale(self.log,(self.log.get_width()//4,self.log.get_height()//6))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            platform_rect = self.log.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            platform_rect.centerx += 60
            platform_rect.centery -= 2
            window.blit(self.log,platform_rect)


    # Platform2 class
    class Platform2:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.log = pygame.image.load("Grass_1.png")
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
            self.log = pygame.transform.scale(self.log,(self.log.get_width()-90,self.log.get_height()-91))
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            platform_rect = self.log.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            platform_rect.centerx += 2
            platform_rect.centery += 0.2
            window.blit(self.log,platform_rect)

    class Dirt:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.dirt = pygame.image.load("Dirt_1.png")
            self.dirt = pygame.transform.scale(self.dirt,(self.dirt.get_width()-90,self.dirt.get_height()-91))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

            dirt_rect = self.dirt.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            dirt_rect.centerx += 2
            dirt_rect.centery += 0.2
            window.blit(self.dirt,dirt_rect)

    class Water:
        def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.color = color
            self.speed = 1
            self.water = pygame.image.load("water_1.png")
            self.water = pygame.transform.scale(self.water,(self.water.get_width()*8,self.water.get_height()*6))
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

            water_rect = self.water.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
            water_rect.centerx += 25
            water_rect.centery += 80
            window.blit(self.water,water_rect)

    # Button class
    class button111():
        def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
            self.color = color
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.text = text
 
        def draw(self,window,outline=None):
            #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
            if outline:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
 
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
 
            if self.text != '':
                font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
                text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
                window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
 
        def isOver(self, pos):
            #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
            if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
                if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                    return True
 
                return False
 
        def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
            if self.isOver(pos):            
                if not self.over:
                    eat.play()
                    self.over = True
            else:
                self.over = False
                
                
        
    


    # displaying Color
    white = (255,255,255)

    # Drawing stuff

    # Drawing player
    playerman = Player(255,440,40,40,white)
    # Drawing Platform
    platform1 = Platform(0,388,130,30,white)
    # Drawing Platform2
    Platform1 = Platform2(7000,470,1,1,white)
    # Drawing Dirt
    dirt1 = Dirt(7000,255,35,35.1,white)
    # Water
    water1 = Water(0,800,500,300,white)
    # List

    # Putting Platform in a list
    platforms = [platform1]
    # Putting Platform2 in a list
    Platforms = [Platform1]
    # Putting Dirt in a list
    dirts = [dirt1]

    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    Level = [
    "  l",
    "l",
    "",
    "  l",
    "  ",
    "l",
    "   ",
    "  l",
    "   ",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "11111111111111111111",
    "22222222222222222222",]
    for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "1":
                new_platform = Platform2(ix*35, iy*36.4, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
                Platforms.append(new_platform)
    for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "2":
                new_dirt = Dirt(ix*35, iy*36.4, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
                dirts.append(new_dirt)
    for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "l":
                new_platform = Platform(ix*110, iy*60, 130,30,(255, 255, 255))
                platforms.append(new_platform)
        

    pause = False

    
    def quitgame():
        pygame.quit()

    def unpause():
        global pause
        pause = False
        
    def paused():

        
        greenbutton10 = button111((0,255,0),190,262,120,43, '')
        greenbutton11 = button111((0,255,0),200,340,100,35, '')
        greenbutton12 = button111((0,255,0),177,437,157,55, '')
        
    

        while pause:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("", largeText)
            TextRect.center = ((700/2),(500/2))
            window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
                
        
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
            button("",190,262,120,43,green,darkgreen,unpause)
            button("",200,340,100,35,red,darkred,quitgame)
            button("",177,437,157,55,blue,darkblue,game_intro)
            window.blit(GP,(0,0))

            if greenbutton10.isOver(pos):
                window.blit(GP2,(0,0))
            if greenbutton11.isOver(pos):
                window.blit(GP3,(0,0))
            if greenbutton12.isOver(pos):
                window.blit(GP4,(0,0))

            
            
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(15)


# This is what happens when you toch the water
    
    lose = False

    
    def quitgame():
        pygame.quit()

    def unlose():
        global lose
        lose = False
        
    def lost():

        
        greenbutton12 = button111((0,255,0),168,285,175,65, '')
        
        
        while lose:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            
            largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("", largeText)
            TextRect.center = ((700/2),(500/2))
            window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
                
        
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            button("",168,285,175,65,blue,darkblue,game_intro)
            window.blit(DD,(0,0))
            

            if greenbutton12.isOver(pos):
                window.blit(DD2,(0,0))


            
            
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(15)
            


    
        

    # redrawing window
    def redrawwindow():
        window.fill((0,0,0))
        window.blit(BG,(0,0))
        
        # bliting a counter the game
        window.blit(text,textRect)
        # showing player on the screen
        playerman.draw()

        # Drawing Platform
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.draw()
        # Drawing Platform2
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.draw()
        # Drawing Dirt
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.draw()
            # Drawing Water
            water1.draw()
        window.blit(M,(0,0))
        window.blit(P,(0,0))
        window.blit(UM,(0,0))
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            
        greenbutton7 = button111((0,255,0),400,146,100,35, '')
        greenbutton8 = button111((0,255,0),400,211,100,35, '')
        greenbutton9 = button111((0,255,0),400,285,100,35, '')
        #greenbutton9.draw(window)
        

        if greenbutton7.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(P2,(0,0))
        if greenbutton8.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(M2,(0,0))
        if greenbutton9.isOver(pos):
            window.blit(UM2,(0,0))
        


    # The conter and how its going look like
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
    score = 0
    text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((150,40))


    fps = 30
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    x = 10
    y = 10

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    old_x = x
    old_y = y

    timer = 0
    Stimer =  0

    # Space down = False
    spcdown = False
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        if playerman.rect.colliderect(water1.rect):
            lose = True
            lost()
            


        greenbutton7 = button111((0,255,0),400,146,100,35, '')
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenbutton7.isOver(pos):
                pause = True
                paused()
                
        greenbutton8 = button111((0,255,0),400,211,100,35, '')
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenbutton8.isOver(pos):
                pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(1000)

        greenbutton9 = button111((0,255,0),400,285,100,35, '')
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenbutton9.isOver(pos):
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)


        if Stimer > 0:
            Stimer += 1
        if Stimer > 900:
            Stimer = 0

        water1.y -= water1.speed
        if Stimer == 0:
            water1.speed += 1
        Stimer += 1


        for Platform in platforms:
            if Platform.y > 510:
                Platform.x = random.randint(0, 470)
                Platform.y = random.randint(-150, -100)
                
        # Mkaing screen go up
        if playerman.y < 250:
            delta = 10
            playerman.y += delta
            for Platform in platforms:
                Platform.y += delta
            for Platform2 in Platforms:
                Platform2.y += delta
            for Dirt in dirts:
                Dirt.y += delta
            water1.y += 9

                
        # Marking screen go down
        if playerman.y > 410:
            playerman.y -= playerman.fall
            for Platform in platforms:
                Platform.y -= playerman.fall
            for Platform2 in Platforms:
                Platform2.y -= playerman.fall
            for Dirt in dirts:
                Dirt.y -= playerman.fall
            water1.y -= playerman.fall
                



            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change = -7
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x_change = 7

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x_change = 0

                x += x_change
                if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
                    x = old_x


      

                
            

        # If keys get pressed
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y




        # Adding one to score every time player jumps
        if not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            spcdown = False  # space released
        
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if not spcdown:
                score += 1  # if space pressed first time
            spcdown = True  # space key is pressed
            text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
            textRect.center = ((150,40))
            

        # Player movment
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
            px -= playerman.speed
            playerman.direction = "lrun"
        elif keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
            px += playerman.speed
            playerman.direction = "run"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "run":
                playerman.direction = "idle"
            else:
                if playerman.direction == "lrun":
                    playerman.direction = "idlel"
        

        if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
            py -= playerman.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_s] and py < 500 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
            py += playerman.speed
            

        # animation for player jump
        if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                playerman.direction = "jump"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "lrun":
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.direction = "ljump"
                    


        platform_rect_list =[p.rect for p in platforms]
        player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
        playerman.rect.topleft = (px,py)


        playerman.y = py
        if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
            playerman.x = px


        

            
        # About isJump
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.y += playerman.fall
            playerman.fall += 1
            playerman.isJump = False

                        

                # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
            collide = False
            for Platform in platforms:
                if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                    collide = True
                    playerman.isJump = False
                    playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                    if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                        playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                    if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                        playerman.x = Platform.rect.right

            
                    # Lets Player jump on top of second Platform
            for Platform2 in Platforms:
                if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform2.rect):
                    collide = True
                    playerman.isJump = False
                    playerman.y = Platform2.rect.top - playerman.height
                    if playerman.rect.right > Platform2.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform2.rect.left - playerman.width:
                        playerman.x = Platform2.rect.left - playerman.width
                    if playerman.rect.left < Platform2.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform2.rect.right + playerman.width:
                        playerman.x = Platform2.rect.right

                               
                    # colliding with floor      
                if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                    collide = True
                    playerman.isJump = False
                    playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                    playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

                # Jumping
            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.fall = 0

        # Jump Count

        else:
            if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
                playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.5
                playerman.JumpCount -= 1
            else:
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10

            
            
        redrawwindow()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    unpause()
    unlose()
game_intro()
main_loop()
```

Comment: So by "pack my code" do you mean, use "pyinstaller" or "cxFreeze" to make it into an executable?  If so could you please include details of what method you used.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not specify, I used pyinstaller.

Comment: I suspect it's having problems finding your files.  When code + resources are packed using pyinstaller (etc.) everything is compressed into a package.  These are usually unpacked into temporary directory when run. But this temp dir is *not* the working directory while the exe is running, so the `GameP1.png` can't be found in the "current" directory at all.  So I'm pretty sure you're question is a duplicate of this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936621/python-pygame-error-when-executing-exe-file/62944866#62944866