# how can I change pytube file to exe

Tags: python, path, exe, pyinstaller, pytube

I already tried using pyinstaller. But it kept showed me 'Fail to execute script' error.
I just want to make this code into exe file successfully.
some said the problem was about relative path and absolute path.
so i changed it by using `os.path.join(os.path.abspath('Downloads'))` but it didn't work.
Btw,it is a program to collect some raps.
and also, since i'm a baby coder,i would be grateful if you feedback about me code.
if you can do Korean, you can answer me in Korean.

```
import pytube
import os
import glob
import time
def formatchange(s):
    s = str(s)
    s = s.replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace("Stream: ", "").replace("itag=", "").replace("mime_type=", "").replace("abr=", "").replace("res=", "").replace("fps=", "").replace("vcodec=", "").replace("acodec=", "").replace("progressive=", "").replace("type=", "").replace(" ", ",").replace("\"", "").split(',')
    del s[0]
    return s

def audio_only(direct,title):
    files = glob.glob(f'{direct}\{title}\*.mp4')
    for x in files:
        if not os.path.isdir(x):
            filename = os.path.splitext(x)
            try:
                os.rename(x,filename[0] + '.mp3')
            except:
                pass
            
    
        
            
def main():
    while 1:
        vv = input("youtube video link>>> ")
        vv = vv.split('&')[0]
        yt = pytube.YouTube(vv)
        title = yt.title
        print(f'\ntitle: {title}\n')
        answer = input('continue??(y/n)>>>')
        if answer == 'y':
            break
        print("try again\n")
    
    videos = yt.streams

    typer = False
    down_dir = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('Downloads'))  #this thing
    print(down_dir)

    list1 = ["타입","화질","fps","코덱","순차주사방식유무","타입"]
    list2 = ["타입","음질","코덱","순차주사방식유무","타입"]

    for i in range(len(videos)):
        print("----------------------------------------")
        a = formatchange(videos[i])
        print(i,end = '\n\n')
        
        if 'video' in a[0]:
            if a[1] == "None":
                a[1] = '소리만 재생only audio'
            if a[4] == "False":
                a[4] = 'False 소리가 안들릴수 있습니다.there might be no audio'
            for i in range(len(list1)):
                print(f'{list1[i]}: {a[i]}')
                
        else:
            for i in range(len(list2)):
                print(f'{list2[i]}: {a[i]}')
        print('\n\n')

    asdf = True
    
    if len(videos) == 0:
        print('found None')
        asdf = False
        
    while 1:
        if asdf:
            i=input('숫자를 입력해 선택하시오.enter number>>> ')
            if i.isdigit() == True and 0<=int(i)<len(videos) :
                i = int(i)
                videos[i].download(down_dir)
                if 'audio' in formatchange(videos[i])[0]:
                    audio_only(down_dir,title)
                print('done')
                os.system('cls')
                break
            print('다시 시도 try agin')
        else:break
            

while 1:
    main()
```

Comment: in `os.path.join(os.path.abspath('Downloads')) ` 'downloads' is a relative path.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716346/windows-pyinstaller-error-failed-to-execute-script-when-app-clicked answer tells you how to run it in debug mode to see the actual cause of the 'script failed' error

Comment: but it just made new path where it been

Comment: You asked python for the absolute path of a relative path,  probably a relative path that didn't exist.

Comment: I fixed it!!! I accidently set --noconsole keyword when I created it