# Failed to execute script error after successful execution exe

Tags: pygame, pyinstaller, exe, fatal-error

I am trying to create an exe file for my pygame game with pyinstaller. The command I am using is `pyinstaller --noconsole 2d_minecraft.py`. It creates the dist folder successfully.

I am getting this error ***after*** a successful execution of the exe file created. This does not happen without the `--noconsole` option.

code:

```
import pymc
import pygame
import random
import perlin_noise

pygame.init()

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 640))
WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT = WIN.get_width(), WIN.get_height()
WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT = 64, 64

FPS = 60

pymc.set_title("2d Minecraft")

class objects():
    to_draw = []
    run = True
    cam_y = (WORLD_HEIGHT/2)*64
    cam_x = (WORLD_WIDTH/2)*64
    block_textures = {
    [...]
    }

class tile():
    [...]

def handle_keys():
    [...]
        
def generate_world():
    [...]

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    tiles = generate_world()

    while objects.run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        objects.to_draw = []

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                objects.run = False
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        for x in range(0, WORLD_WIDTH):
            for y in range(0, WORLD_HEIGHT):
                objects.to_draw.append(tiles[x][y])

        handle_keys()

        pymc.draw_window(WIN, objects.to_draw, fill=(0, 150, 255))
    main()

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Should your argument be `--noconsole` ([doc](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-w)) or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40716346/2280890)

Comment: does not help looked already but thanks anyway

Comment: If the other answers don't help, please edit your question to include a [mcve] so that it's possible to assist you.

Comment: edited its alot of code  :)

Comment: So your python script is filename.exe?

Comment: my script is called 2d_minecraft.py the exe file is called 2d_minecraft.exe. silly me, so many typos. :)

Comment: I would guess that the error is caused by failing to find a resource, are you using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/2280890) to locate your images?

Comment: no but I am putting my texture folder in with the exe file after I pyinstall it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! All I needed to do was change `exit()` to `sys.exit()` (and add `import sys` as well).